# How to fix "can't load file ...\Activate.ps1 because script execution is disabled on this system" when trying to setup venv for Python on VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv

I'm using VS Code and I have followed the steps in the docs to set it up for Python development: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial.

But when trying to run a program I get the error:

> can´t load the file C:\V\VSCode\Python.venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1 because script execution is disabled on this system. For more information, see the about_Execution_Policies.

Even though I get the error, the program runs fine.

Python version: 3.12.1
VSCode version: 1.85.1

[image: This is the environment I have created]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the command `get-executionpolicy` to verify your execution policy setting. If you get `Restricted`, it means No scripts can be run and you can only use Windows PowerShell in interactive mode. If you get `AllSigned`, it means you can run only scripts that have been digitally signed by a trusted publisher. If you get `RemoteSigned`, it means you can run scripts that was created locally, but scripts that is downloaded must be digitally signed by a trusted publisher. If you get `Unrestricted`, then there are no restrictions at all. This allows you to run unsigned scripts from any source but will warn when a script has been downloaded from the Internet.

To remove the restrictions, you can either run `set-executionpolicy remotesigned` (preferable) or `set-executionpolicy unrestricted` (if you're running as admin). After this, you can activate your virtual environment using`venv\Scripts\activate`.

To get more information on Set-ExecutionPolicy, run `get-help set-executionpolicy`. See [Setting the PowerShell Execution Policy](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2702/setting-the-powershell-execution-policy/) for more.

Comment: I found `set-executionpolicy -scope currentuser remotesigned` to be more appropriate in case one can't have admin privileges.

Answer (score 1):

> can´t load the file C:\V\VSCode\Python.venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1
> because script execution is disabled on this system.

You're seeing this error because VSCode tries to activate your virtual environment by running the `Activate.ps1` script. However this is blocked by the execution policy.

You can open PowerShell as an administrator and run the following command to change it:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

You can also try to set **cmd** as the default terminal instead of PowerShell.

[image]