How to fix import library or packages path for Anaconda environments in python?
I have recently uninstalled Anaconda, installed Python 3.12.4 globally and then reinstalled Anaconda again in my Windows 11 machine.
When I activate my Anaconda virtual environment it picks the Python from Anaconda:
conda activate HQ
(HQ) PS C:\Users\vinee> which python
/c/Users/vinee/anaconda3/envs/HQ/python

But when I check the pip location then it points towards the global one instead of virtual environment:
(HQ) PS C:\Users\vinee> pip --version 
pip 24.3.1 from C:\Users\vinee\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip (python 3.12)

All the library paths are getting picked up wrongly even in virtual environments.
My path:

Yesterday I was also facing PowerShell virtual environment activation issues (see How to fix "can't load file ...\Activate.ps1 because script execution is disabled on this system" when trying to setup venv for Python on VS Code?) as well when I created this virtual environment. I have fixed this issue today only.

I recommend that you uninstall the other python that you installed "globally". Aside from that, use python -m pip everywhere, much more fool proof, esspecially when you have a confusing setup with multiple installations of python

Thanks @FlyingTeller. Uninstalling All other python has definitely helped and now I am getting the correct location after restarting my machine (HQ) C:\Users\vinee>pip --version pip 24.3.1 from C:\Users\vinee\anaconda3\envs\HQ\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.12)

Perfect. If you need to use a different python version in the future, simply create a conda environment for it conda create -n py312 python=3.12 for example

@FlyingTeller Thanks, now I am using this command only but I created a mess because I thought of removing Anaconda and and when I tried creating virtual env & use through vscode then I got stuck because of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77711479/how-to-fix-cant-load-file-activate-ps1-because-script-execution-is-disable
